# apache rewrite wild card subdomain name to query string?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I've search google and read many websites, but still have no clue. Basically, I want to internally redirect subdomain names to query strings. Here's some example:

Users type user1.mywebsite.com

The url above stays the same to users, but I want the server to intepret it as mywebsite.com/user?name=user1

Can someone help me? Thanks.

Comment: For future readers, found the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11086999/mod-rewrite-strip-away-subdomain-and-convert-to-url-parameter

Answer (score 1):

You can only match the hostname in `RewriteCond`.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (.+)\.mywebsite.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ mywebsite.com/user?name=%1
```