# mod_rewrite: strip away subdomain and convert to URL parameter

Tags: mod-rewrite

I have a web app, where I keep a subdomain for every client eg: http://clientNo32.myApp.com
Due to some server hazzling I have to forward this stuff to my new server at http://123.456.78:1002/clientNo32/app/index.php

The folder "clientNo32" does NOT exist, it's only a parameter I want to get from the URL.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: So what do you want to convert `/clientNo32/app/index.php` to?

Comment: I'd like to change it to /app/index.php?cId=clientNo32 -- the cId variable should be attached to EVERY querystring. 

The simplest way would be using sessions, but my clients work on 2 or 3 workspaces SIMULTANOUSLY. So I can't use sessions, as you can't have multiple sessions in multiple browser instances ... Am I right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're trying to do something like this?

```
RewriteEngine On

# Don't know if you need this, exclude www hosts
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www [NC]

# Make sure we don't already have a "cId" in the query string
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !cId=

# match the subdomain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^\.]+)\.myapp.com$ [NC]

# add subdomain to URI as a query string
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /app/index.php?cId=%1 [L,QSA]
```

This makes it so when you request anything starting with http://clientNo32.myApp.com/, it gets rewritten to `/app/index.php?cId=clientNo32`